# Integration Rich client application with HP load runner

Tags: performance, performance-testing, loadrunner

We use Teamcenter software at our environment and it is a rich client Java application. We wanted to measure its performance by using the HP load runner software. However this is not working as the load runner is not able to start the application.

The support team of HP got back to us with the statement as below:

> The root of the issue in fact that AUT has unexpected by Vugen
>   multi-process hierarchy, Vugen cannot record process outside of
>   single-root tree, specified at Start Recording Dialog. You can ask
>   your app Dev team to rebuild the software so all new process will be
>   children of parent process.

Can you please help me understand what can be done here?. Has anyone experienced such a problem?.

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: Which protocols did you try? Maybe using something like HTTP is enough for your case?

Answer (score 0):

Big questions:

1. What is the next upstream architectural component from the client?
2. What well known ports/protocols are identified by a wireshark trace of your application?

When querying "The Google" using the terms "acuity teamcenter architecture" I ran across a SOA whitepaper that would suggest that at least some interfaces can be exercised via a standard HTTP client which could be captured via proxy.   I do not know if the Java client leverages this same interface model, but if it does then changing your global application proxy to point to an instance of the LoadRunner HTTP recording proxy will then allow you to record the conversation.